# Error uploading files to SharePoint using office365-rest-api when '%' is in the filename

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using the office365-rest-api to upload files to SharePoint online, and everything works fine, except when I have a filename which contains a % character.  The resultant filename in SharePoint has a '25' added to it.  So if the filename that I am uploading is 'First 50% of candidates.xls'  the filename that ends up in SharePoint online is 'First 50%25 of candidates.xls'

My code that is doing the upload is :-

```
ctx=ClientContext('https://mycomp.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/').with_credentials(userCredentials)
SP_Location="TheLibrary/TheFolder"
fileName="First 50% of Candidates.xls"
path="../../path/First 50% of Candidates.xls"
with open(path, 'rb') as content_file:
 fileContent=content_file.read()
targetFolderUrl=ctx.web.ensure_folder_path(SP_Location).execute_query()
targetFile=targetFolderUrl.upload_file(fileName,fileContent)
ctx.execute_query()
```

How do I format the filename so it arrives in SharePoint unadulterated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The % character is reserved in urls. I would either use a library to URL encode your filename, or manually replace the % with %25 before sending.

You can see a reference to these characters here.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: Ah, I see. Well I tried manually replacing the '%' character with %25, and it appeared in sharepoint as 'First 50%25 of Candidates.xls'   I used the python string.replace('%','%25') method. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, that won't work then. Are you able to download the file from sharepoint? Does it still contain the %, or is it just displaying in the URL?

Comment: Upon looking further, see this post. It looks like it may be a configuration thing on your sharepoint site to allow these characters. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/sharepoint-online-support-for-and-in-file-names/m-p/125877

Comment: Yes, I can download the file and it is still named with the 50%25 rather than just 50%.  I can go into SharePoint and edit the filename to be 50% and that works fine, so the site allows it, and I have confirmed our tenancy does allow these special characters. so it's just getting lost in the API upload somewhere.